# Line highlighting does not work in Nuxt Content & ShikiJS

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I use the latest version of Nuxt Content. This is my config

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  content: {
    highlight: {
      theme: 'material-theme-darker',
    },
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxt/content',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
})
```

When I render an .md with the following markdown:

```
<div class="flex justify-start mb-4">
  <VToggle v-model="fixSpacing"> // [!code highlight]
    Make the hero section shorter
  </VToggle>
</div>
```

The snippet is highlighted, however the line is not. It get's the `.highlighted` class, as I can see from the HTML rendered, but the class does not have any styles. Instead the default background color is applied.

Same happens with other Shiki transformers. Classes applied but they don't have styles. How to fix this?

[image]